# Почему bootstrap-multiselect в приложении ASP.NET Core 2.0 в модальном окне(bootstrap) не всегда отрисовывается?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, asp.net

Использую в модальном окне dropdown list с multi-selsect (davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)

Библиотеки подключены - иначе этот список не работал бы, но раз-через раз(не могу сказать что чередуется просто, имеет непонятную периодичность) при открытии модального окна не срабатывает
Это как должно выглядеть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это как периодически происходит(при открытии модального окна):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В js я слабоват, думаю проблема в модальном окне. Я его подгружаю как частичное представление.
Подключенные библиотеки в _Layout.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - QAManagementTool</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />        
        <link href="~/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
        <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">   
            <div class="navbar-header navbar-logo">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand"><img id="logoImg" src="~/images/MagnifiQALogoColorWhite.png"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                @*<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>*@
                @await Html.PartialAsync("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2017 - QAManagementTool</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        @*<script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>*@
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Фрагмент где вызываю модальное окно:

```html
@model IEnumerable<QAManagementTool.Models.ViewModels.ProjectVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Projects</h2>
<a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Home" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-container" class="btn btn-default">Add project</a>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade hidden-print" @*tabindex="-1"*@ role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
            @Html.DisplayName("Name")
        </th>
        <th>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
            @Html.DisplayName("TrelloBoard")
        </th>
        <th>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            @Html.DisplayName("Modification")
        </th>
        <th>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            @Html.DisplayName("By")
        </th>
        <th>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            @Html.DisplayName("DateTime")
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-id="@item.Id" title="View details project @item.ProjectName" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-container">@Html.DisplayFor(it => item.ProjectName)</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="@item.TrelloBoardURL" title="Go to TrelloBoard"><img src="~/images/trello-logo-blue.png" height="20" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>@item.Modification</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>@item.By</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>@item.EntryDateTime</label>
            </td>
        </tr>       
    }
</table>
@section scripts {
    @* The normal bootstrap behavior is to only grab the content for the modal once, if you need to pull in different partial views then the data on the modal will have to be cleared.*@
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#modal-container').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
                var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
                var url = button.attr("href");
                var modal = $(this);

                // note that this will replace the content of modal-content ever time the modal is opened
                modal.find('.modal-content').load(url);
            });
            $('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                $(this).removeData('modal');
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Модальное окно:

```html
@model QAManagementTool.Models.ViewModels.ProjectECVM
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add new project";
}
<div id="target">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Create new project</h4>
    </div>
    <form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Home" id="createProject" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="REPLACE-WITH" data-ajax-update="#target" onsubmit="validate();">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group input-group-addon">
                <label asp-for="ProjectName" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="ProjectName" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"></div>
            <div class="form-group input-group-addon">
                <label asp-for="TrelloBoardURL" class="control-label">TrelloBoardURL</label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="TrelloBoardURL" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group input-group-addon">
                <label  class="control-label">Users</label>
                <select id="selectUser" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.UsersList))", multiple="multiple"></select>  
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"></div>
            <div class="form-group input-group-addon">
                <label class="control-label">Sharing access</label>
                <select id="selectAccess" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.AccessList))"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="btn btn-default addUser">Add User</span>   
            </div>
            <div class="form-group input-group-addon">
                <label class="control-label">Who has access</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="table-responsive panel panel-default">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-fixed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayName("Specific people can access")
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayName("Change")
                                </th>
                                <th>

                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tableUser" class="information_json_addUser">
                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.projectUsers.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="user">
                                        <label name="projectUsers[0].Name">@Model.projectUsers[i].Name</label>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="projectUsers[0].Name" value=@Model.projectUsers[i].Name>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="access">
                                        <label name="projectUsers[0].Access">@Model.projectUsers[i].Access.ToString("f")</label>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="projectUsers[0].Access" value=@Model.projectUsers[i].Access.ToString("f")>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="btn btn-default btn-sm delUser">Del</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="validSummary"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
```

js-файл, кот как я понимаю периодически не отрабатывает(но неотрабатывает лишь что что касается multiselsect, валидация работает нормально с него):

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#selectUser').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: false
    });   
});
$(function () {
    var countUser = 0;
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.delUser',
        function () {
            countUser--;
            jQuery(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });
    jQuery('.addUser').click(function () {
        var selectUserList = $('#selectUser').val() || [];
        for (i = 0; i < selectUserList.length; ++i) {
            countUser++;
            jQuery('.information_json_addUser').append(
                '<tr>' +
                '<td class="user"><label name="projectUsers[' + countUser + '].Name">' + selectUserList[i] + '</label>' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="projectUsers[' + countUser + '].Name" value=' + selectUserList[i] + ' /></td> + ' +
                '<td class="access"><label name="projectUsers[' + countUser + '].Access">' + $('#selectAccess').val() + '</label>' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="projectUsers[' + countUser + '].Access" value=' + $('#selectAccess').val() + ' /></td> + ' +
                '<td><span class="btn btn-default btn-sm delUser">Del</span></td>' +
                '</tr>'
            );
        }
    });
    //Проверка введенных данных при редактировании или создании проекта
    function validate() {
        valid = true;
        //проверка на наличие одного и того же пользователя в листе к проекту
        jQuery('#validSummary').empty();
        var tdu = $(".user").children("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < tdu.length; i++) {
            if (valid) {
                for (var j = 1 + i; j < tdu.length; j++) {
                    if (tdu[i].attributes["value"].value == tdu[j].attributes["value"].value) {
                        jQuery('#validSummary').append(
                            '<label>To the project, you can not add the same user more than once</label></br>'
                        );
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //проверка на наличие более одного собственника для проекта или отсутствие собственника
        var tda = $(".access").children("input");//возвращает массив всех <td id="access">
        var countOwner = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < tda.length; i++) {
            if (tda[i].attributes["value"].value == "Owner")
                countOwner++;
            if (countOwner > 1) {
                jQuery('#validSummary').append(
                    '<label>The project can not have more than one owner</label></br>'
                );
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (countOwner == 0) {
            jQuery('#validSummary').append(
                '<label>The project must have at least one owner</label></br>'
            );
            valid = false;
        }
        //проверка на пустое поле имени
        var projectNameVal = $("#ProjectName").val();
        if (projectNameVal == "") {
            jQuery('#validSummary').append(
                '<label>The project can not have empty name</label></br>'
            );
            valid = false;
        }
        if (!valid) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

кода выложил немного с излишком, помогите, кто знает в чем проблема может быть.

Comment: Нашел причину. Модальное окно открывается у меня в одном и том же месте от двух разных кнопок - создание и редактирование. Путем задротского наблюдения)) установил, что не срабатывает список лишь на редактировании(правда потом он и на открытие переходит как неработающий некоторое время, видимо кэш старается). В модальном окне на редактирование есть еще одно модальное окно на подтверждение удаления, так вот если его убрать - то все отлично работает.

Comment: Теперь осталось понять как второе модальное портило картину(оно кстати в отличи от первого не загружается извне, а находиться в том же файле)